# $2^{O(\log \log n)} = O(\log n)$ prove or disprove

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics, computational-complexity

I need to prove or disprove this:
$$2^{O(\log\log n)} = O(\log n)$$

I haven't found anything like that through search.
I would like to have some help.
Thanks.

Comment: Hint: Taking the $\log$ to be base $2$, you can transform $2^{2\log\log n}$. Do you think it is $O(\log n)$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that the function $10 \log_2 \log n$ is $O(\log \log n)$. But, $2^{10 \log_2 \log n} = 2^{\log_2 ((\log n)^{10})} = (\log n)^{10}$, which isn't $O(\log n)$.

Answer (score 0):

Just transform to $\log_2$ :

$$2^{c \log \log n}=\left ( 2^{\frac{\log_2(\log n)}{\log_2 e}} \right)^c=\left (\log n \right )^{\frac{c}{\log_2 e}}$$